# Creating manually observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am using for my frontend development [OpenUI5](http://openui5.org/) and it does not support rxjs.

For example, I want to listen the press Button from [OpenUI5](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Button.html) event and could not do like

```
var source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(input, 'press');

var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x) {
    console.log('Next: Clicked!');
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Error: %s', err);
  },
  function () {
    console.log('Completed');
  });
```

Because the Button control does not implement event listener.

So I have to create Observable on my own, how to create a hot Observable?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to accomplish? For events wrapping them in `fromEvent` is an excellent approach (and `subscribe` makes them hot)

Comment: I want to reach, to handle press event with rxjs. https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Button.html#attachPress

Answer (score 1):

If `fromEvent` does not work for you, or for instance you want to wire multiple events to the same stream you can do something like this:

```
function mouseAllTheThingsStream(){
  const target = document.getElementById('#content');
  return Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
    target.onmousemove(evt => observer.onNext(evt));
    target.onmousedown(evt => observer.onNext(evt));

    window.setTimeout(() => observer.onCompleted(), 30 * 1000);

    return () => {
      // cleanup; unsubscribe from events manually
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: `window.setTimeout(() => observer.onCompleted(), 30 * 1000);` what is this for?

Comment: To give an example of completion for your custom created observable

Comment: why do I have to completed it?

Comment: You are not required to. See the docs https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/create.md for more extensive examples

Comment: the example that you mentioned above, it seems not to be working. When you read the doc https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Button.html#attachPress, there is a press event that I can not use rxjs as you mentioned above.